# Get m4v to autoplay while hidden in iOS

Tags: html5-video, mobile-website

```
<video muted controls="true" loop id="v" width="100%" height="100%" src="pattern.m4v">
```

The video plays when I hit it direct on iOS (localhost/patter.m4v) yet it absolutely will NOT play when I hit my index.html. In fact, I can't even get the video to play by tapping on it directly even when visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took way too long to solve for how simple of a problem it is AND how simple the solution was.

Out of all the articles I read, this article on [html5 video in webkit](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) helped the most. If my solution does not work for you, I highly encourage you to consult that link as the solution to your problem is likely in there.

**Problems**

1. For whatever reason, my `<canvas>` element was over my `<video>` element, even if not visually. If this is your problem, there are tricks like `position: absolute` and/or `z-index:999`
2. I needed `playinline` for my video or it would only play full screen. Note that `autoplay` and `videoElement.play()` only work with `playinline`.

**Cliff notes:**

- Apple relaxed rules on html video in iOS 10
- `autoplay` *works* in iOS10 (a)
- `playsinline`*works* in iOS10 (a)

**Code**

```
<video playsinline muted controls loop autoplay id="v" width="400" height="400" src="pattern.m4v">
```

a: As long as it abides by the rules listed in the link above (second paragraph)